# Implementing a static "memory" Map

Tags: java, dictionary, static

I am writing a small application to be used for testing purposes that accepts SOAP calls, generated UID's for each call, and returns this UID.  The UID's need to be stored on the server so I thought I'd use a simple static Map to store them.

I created a new class:

**MemoryMap.java**

```
public class MemoryMap {

    static Map<String, String> memoryMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    static void printMapContents() {
        for (Entry<String, String> pair : memoryMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key = [" + pair.getKey() + "]");
            System.out.println("Value = [" + pair.getValue() + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

This is then used with the calls:

```
MemoryMap.memoryMap.put(UID, "testString");
MemoryMap.printMapContents();
```

and...

```
MemoryMap.memoryMap.remove(parameters.getUID());
MemoryMap.printMapContents();
```

This works fine, but I can't think whether this is the recommended way to implement a single Map for this purpose.

Comment: What's wrong with a normal hashmap?

Comment: Do you want the size of the map to be fixed? And do you need to remove the old k-v pairs automatically by expire time or some other mechanism?

Comment: Why are you removing entries as you print them?

Comment: And generally why are you doing all that?

Comment: Another point: as you use unique (UUID) keys you don;t need Concurrent  map at all, ordinary HashMap will do the job. And - **don't** use `Iterator`, foreach loop is more than sufficient.

Comment: @Germann Arlington: Its a simple call simulator.  When the client requests a call creation, it requires a UUID returned.  Then when the request to end the call comes in, it gives the UUID for that call, which is then removed.  Thanks for the tip re: foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application must mock a backend, e.g., a database, I recommend abstracting the map away in some datastore interface, and then provide your application with a singleton scoped instance of an implementation of this interface backed by a map. For example:

```
interface MyDataStore<V>{
  V retrieve(UUID id);
  void remove(UUID id);
}

public final class MockDataStore implements MyDataStore<String>{
  private final static MockDataStore instance = new MockDataStore();
  public static MockDataStore instance(){
    return instance;
  }
  private MockDataStore(){}
  private final ConcurrentHashMap<UUID,String> m = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<UUID,String>();
  @Override
  String retrieve(UUID id){
    return m.get(id);
  }
  @Override
  void remove(UUID id){
    m.remove(id);
  }
}
```

Then tomorrow you can swap the implementation for something that speaks to an actual database. This is a very rough approximation of an ORM system.

Even better, I would start with a database right off the bat. You could use an in memory database (like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)) so that you could replace it with an actual database (with possibly some minor migration issue) when you need to.

Finally, if your storage needs grow, e.g., you need tables and relations among them, I recommend looking at JPA and one of its implementations, e.g., [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).

Answer (score -2):

Your server accepts SOAP requests, most likely this is done in several threads. `ConcurrentHashMap` should work just fine.

Comment: OP use `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated answer.